# Como traduzir "De Londres com carinho"?

Tags: tradução

Queria saber como traduzir essa expressão para o Inglês,  pois todas aquelas que consegui achar ou não  são corretas ou soam estranhas.

Eu estava escrevendo um cartão postal para um amigo.

Comment: Convinha dar algum contexto para que seja mais fácil de traduzir.

Comment: @JorgeB Adicionei o contexto

Comment: Se estiver a procura de uma forma de terminar o cartão que não tenha necessariamente de ser a escrita e dado o contexto, aconselhava `Best wishes from London` (amigo próximo) ou `Best regards from London` (conhecido/amigo distante). O problema do carinho e que não traduz bem o sentido para Inglês. Tal como o Arthur disse (e a norma pelo Reino Unido) seria o `From London with love`, em que o `love` não significa explicitamente o nosso sentido de amor (um exemplo disto e a expressao do dia a dia `Lots of love` que em Portugues se escreve `Muito amor` mas que pode significar `Muito carinho`.

Comment: A carta é toda escrita em inglês? E o amigo que vai recebê-la, é falante de qual idioma?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eu usaria "from London, with love", uma expressão que é bem normal. Não sei se "love" soa estranho no seu contexto...

Comment: Eu preferiria evitar essa expressão, adicionei um pouco de contexto

Comment: Me parece normal a expressão, mesmo com o contexto novo. De qualquer forma, por questões culturais até entendo a motivação em se buscar alguma alternativa. Falando em questões culturais, depende de onde é o amigo também. Um brasileiro pode achar estranho um amigo falar "love", alguém de outro país pode achar normal.

Answer (score 4):

"From London, with love" está correto.

Prova: a vida inteira como falante de inglês ;)